# algorithm/complexity - most efficient way to solve

Tags: sorting, hashtable, complexity-theory

So the question is this.  I have the following as an example input,

|ID | A | B |

|2  |100|200|

|3  |110|190|

|4  |105|145|

|1  |90 |150|

|5  |102|198|

and the goal is the following.  For each ID x, compute the number of other IDs y where A of y is greater that A of x and B of y is less than B of x.  So the output of the above example should be

|ID|count|

|3 |0    |

|4 |0    |

|1 |1    |

|5 |2    |

|2 |3    |

Where ID 3 has count 0 because it has the largest A. Obviously you could do O(n^2) exhaustive search but that would be inefficient.

My algorithm is the following. Sort the input twice - once by A and once by B, getting

|ID | A | B |

|1  |90 |150|

|2  |100|200|

|5  |102|198|

|4  |105|145|

|3  |110|190|

and

|ID | A | B |

|2  |100|200|

|5  |102|198|

|3  |110|190|

|1  |90 |150|

|4  |105|145|

Then start with the first ID in the first sorted table (ID=1) and get the ID's with a larger A value (i.e. the ID's below it - 2,5,4,3) then lookup ID=1 on the second sorted table and look at the ID's below it and everytime one is found in the original set of ID's a counter is incremented - in this case the only ID below 1 in the second table is 4 and 4 is in {2,5,4,3} so the output is 1.

So sorting is O(nlogn) and I believe the rest of the operations are constant.  Is there a better method?

Comment: The operations after the sort are definitely not constant.

Comment: really? For each ID in the first sorted table you would insert the ID's below it in a hashtable (constant), then for each ID below the current ID in the second sorted table you would do a hashtable lookup (constant) and if the lookup finds a value -> increment a counter (constant).

Comment: u might be right because u would have to search through the unsorted ID column of the second table for each ID in the first table.